# is Adobe AIR getting restricted by Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, air, adobe, flash-builder

Apple has notified with below statement, so wanted to make sure it doesn't mean to restrict AIR for developing iOS apps ?

(https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a#top)

Make Your Apps Work Seamlessly with iOS 7

December 17, 2013

Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be optimized for iOS 7. Learn more about preparing your apps by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

Thanks,

Sanniv.

Comment: We received a reminder today:  Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK.   This sounds like it will be trouble for Flex and the Adobe Air / Flash created apps.  Did you find anything out with more clarity?

Comment: No, still no clarity on it, although few people messaged that Air 4.0 might be pointing to Xcode 5 here http://forums.adobe.com/message/5940703#5940703

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 1st Feb this has become an issue.

Apple has rejected an app update of mine built with Flash CS6 / AIR 4.0.0.1390 with error:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates
> submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK."
> at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

I found this question while searching for a solution. With a lot more searching I then found this [page](http://forums.adobe.com/message/6010311), which highlights the same issue and has a post from an Adobe employee with the solution:

> Hi All,
> The issue has been fixed and the build 4.0.0.1619 is available for **[mac](http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/air/air4-0_sdk_mac.tbz2)** and **[window](http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/air/air4-0_sdk_win.zip)**.
> Please let us know if you will face any issues.
>
> Regards, Nimit

I hope this helps others get to the solution quicker than I did.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can go with **AIR 3.9**. I think this will clarify your doubt.

> Compile with AIR 3.9 and you should be good to go. Adobe recent update
>   to AIR made app created with AIR compatible with iOS 7

Reference links:

- [Link 1](http://apache-flex-development.2333347.n4.nabble.com/Apple-s-XCode-5-requirement-td33553.html)
- [Link 2](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5715077#5715077)

Comment: My question is whether Apple is making Xcode 5 compulsory... "submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 AND must be optimized for iOS 7"

Comment: As of now, IT IS NOT. You can submit app made in Xcode 4.6.3 or earlier. If it is not compatible for iOS 7, then also it won't reject. But it should be compatible of iPhone 5 screen resolution.